# Using credstash in Python

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, credstash

I've installed [credstash](https://github.com/fugue/credstash) on my computer.  I'm able to use commands like "credstash get [credential]" while in the command prompt.

However, when in a python interpreter, after I use "import credstash" I am getting syntax errors when attempting to use the "credstash get [credential]" command:

```
>>> import credstash
>>> credstash get credstash
   File "<stdin>", line 1
    credstash get credstash
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That syntax is for command line, for python you should use `credstash.getAllSecrets()` or `credstash.getSecret()`

Comment: Do you by chance know if where I could get the documentation for Python syntax?  I wasn't seeing it on their github page anywhere.

Comment: No, I tried to find it but was unable to get it. You can try using IPython and it will let you know all possible functions using <tab> key.

Comment: @Keefer @harshil9968
If any of you got it working, can you please share an example code for `credstash.getSecret()`

Comment: @itz-azhar see here: https://github.com/fugue/credstash/blob/c43f5dcfde1348df639cb33d78dc1beb267ed582/credstash.py#L468

credstash.getSecret("<secret-key>", "<version_or_empty_string>", "<region>", "<dynamo_table>", <{"context-key": "context-value"}>)